# Using python bytes with winrt

Tags: python, windows, windows-runtime

I'm attempting to use `BitmapDecoder` from the winrt package with bytes I've read from a file with python.

I can do it if I use winrt to read the bytes from the file:

```py
import os 

from winrt.windows.storage import StorageFile, FileAccessMode
from winrt.windows.graphics.imaging import BitmapDecoder

async def process_image(path):
    # get image from disk
    file = await StorageFile.get_file_from_path_async(os.fspath(path))
    stream = await file.open_async(FileAccessMode.READ)
    decoder = await BitmapDecoder.create_async(stream)
    return await decoder.get_software_bitmap_async()
```

The problem is that I'd really like to use the bytes in python-land before sending them to `BitmapDecoder` instead of getting them with `StorageFile`.

Browsing the MS docs, I see there's an `InMemoryRandomAccessStream`, which sounds like what I want, but I can't seem to get that working.  I tried this:

```py
from winrt.windows.storage.streams import InMemoryRandomAccessStream, DataWriter
stream = InMemoryRandomAccessStream()
writer = DataWriter(stream)
await writer.write_bytes(bytes_)
```

That gives me `RuntimeError: The parameter is incorrect.` for the `await writer.write_bytes(bytes_)` line.

Not sure what to try next.

Comment: What is `bytes_`? A DataReader would seem more appropriate, but it depends what you're trying to do with the file bytes.

Comment: It's bytes I read from a file with Python. Aka, `open("image.png", "rb")`. I will eventually use it with OcrEngine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use python bytes you do the following.  The key was `writer.write_bytes` is not async and calling `writer.store_async()`.

```py
async def process_image(bytes_):
    stream = InMemoryRandomAccessStream()
    writer = DataWriter(stream)
    writer.write_bytes(bytes_)
    writer.store_async()
    stream.seek(0)

    decoder = await BitmapDecoder.create_async(stream)
    return await decoder.get_software_bitmap_async()
```